# Docker AWS ECR error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character 'p' after top-level value: "404 page not found\n"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

Had an issue with not being able to push or pull from an AWS ECR registry with the following cryptic error:

```
error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character 'p' after top-level value: "404 page not found\n"
```

Several hours of googling indicated it was a protocol issue. It turns out the image name:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/snowshu__test
```

was the issue: **AWS ECR errors when the image name contains double underscores.**

This contradicts ECR naming [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediastore/latest/ug/containers-rules-for-names.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have two underscores next to each other in a repository name.

As per the [Docker Registry API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/):

> A component of a repository name must be at least one lowercase, alpha-numeric characters, optionally separated by periods, dashes or underscores. More strictly, it must match the regular expression `[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*`.

Comment: Good find. Lots of layers of obfuscation here between ECR to evaluating regex in the docker api docs, feel like this could be bubbled up a little cleaner somewhere personally.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the image to

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/snowshu_test
```

solved the issue.